# Is it Possible to not copy all 65,537 cells when copying a column in Open Office

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice, copy-paste, spreadsheet

I'm using Open Office 3.01 on OS X.  When I select an entire column of data by clicking its header, and the copy that to the clipboard, Open Office appears to copy all 65,537 cells to the clipboard.  If I paste the data into a text editor, I'll get a file with 65,537 lines.  This behavior is inconsistent with other spread sheet programs I've used.

Is there any way to change this behavior so it only copies down the the last cell with data in it?  That is, if I have a column with 1034 rows, I'd like to be able to click a column header, selct copy, and have only the 1034 cells of data in the clipboard, not 65,537 cells of data.

I realize I could manually select just the data I wanted to.  I'm not interested in that.  I'm interested in getting open office to behave like the other spread sheet programs I use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

1. Select the first cell in the column.
2. Type Ctrl+Shift+Down-Arrow

That will select only the cells with values in the column; at least in Excel.

Comment: Works in OOCalc, too.

Comment: +1 for close, and better than nothing.  One the Mac version of open office Cmd+Shift+Downarrow will select down to the last item if all the cells are filled, but it does some weird skipping around if there are empty cells.